# Running puppeteer in Ruby on Rails controller kills the Docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, google-chrome, pdf, puppeteer

In Rails application I am trying to generate PDF basing on HTML page using Grover gem:
https://github.com/Studiosity/grover

PDF is generated properly, but just after that my Docker container is instantly killed. Problem doesn't occur in local environment, only inside docker.

Controller action:

```
   def generate_pdf
    grover = Grover.new('http://google.com', format: 'A4')

    pdf = grover.to_pdf

    send_data(pdf, filename: 'dummypdf.pdf', type: 'application/pdf')
  end
```

config/initializers/grover.rb

```
Grover.configure do |config|
  config.options = {
    format: 'A4',
    margin: {
      top: '5px',
      bottom: '10cm'
    },
    viewport: {
      width: 640,
      height: 480
    },
    prefer_css_page_size: true,
    emulate_media: 'screen',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 0, # Timeout in ms. A value of `0` means 'no timeout'
    request_timeout: 10000, # Timeout when fetching the content (overloads the `timeout` option)
    convert_timeout: 20000, # Timeout when converting the content (overloads the `timeout` option, only applies to PDF conversion)
    launch_args: ['--font-render-hinting=medium', '--no-sandbox', '--lang=ja', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-gpu', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
    wait_until: 'domcontentloaded'
  }
end
```

Server log:

```
test_container_1           | 14:54:11 rails.1   | 2022-02-18 14:54:11.885970 I [7:puma server threadpool 003] {request_id: d9fc817c-1a51-4c25-80ac-da0f5c224f34} (4.743s) ProfilesController -- Completed #generate_pdf -- { :controller => "ProfilesController", :action => "generate_pdf", :params => { "kid_id" => "2" }, :format => "HTML", :method => "GET", :path => "/records/2/profile/generate_pdf", :status => 200, :view_runtime => 7.61, :allocations => 51203, :status_message => "OK" }
test_container_1           | 14:54:12           | exited with code 0
test_container_1           | 14:54:12 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
test_container_1           | 14:54:12           | exited with code 0
test_container_1           | 14:54:12 rails.1   | - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
test_container_1           | 14:54:12 rails.1   | Exiting
test_container_1           | 14:54:12           | exited with code 0
test_container_1           | 14:54:12 rails.1   | terminated by SIGTERM
test_container_1           | 14:54:12 webpack.1 | exited with code 0
```

I will be grateful for any suggestions how to deal with this issue (I also tried Dhalang gem instead of Grover but the result was the same)

Comment: That's how Docker works. When the process running in the container finishes, the container shuts down. What do you expect your container to do when it has generated the PDF?

Comment: @hans-kilian It is running rails server and webpacker, it is whole application, not only pdf generation. So I expect the server should continue working.

Comment: The thing that strikes me is the message `sending SIGTERM to all processes` from 'system'. I don't enough about Rails to have a guess at why it does that, but that might cause the main process to exit. Do you get that message when you run locally?

Comment: No, it happens only in Docker. I think it is somehow related with Puppeteer / Chrome, since it occurs when using both Grover and Dhalang gems.

Comment: It seems that running the container using `dumb-init` solves the problem, but to be honest I am not sure why.